# Time Stamp value not inserting in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table in Oracle:

```
DESC TIME_PERIOD
Name       Null     Type         
---------- -------- ------------ 
TIME_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(2)    
START_TIME NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) 
END_TIME   NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)
```

I am inserting values, but values are not inserted. I am using the following query.

```
INSERT INTO TIME_PERIOD (TIME_ID,START_TIME,END_TIME)
   VALUES (1, TO_DSINTERVAL('0 23:59:59'), TO_DSINTERVAL('0 23:59:59'));
```

How can I insert value in Oracle?

I want time like this 
10:00 Am
11:00Am

1:00pm

Comment: You have specified two insert columns, but come with three values...

Comment: `TO_DSINTERVAL` returns an **interval** not a `timestamp`

Comment: A timestamp always has a date part. Oracle doesn't have a data type that only holds a time; a DS interval is as close as you can get really. Or you can use a timestamp with a nominal date part. How will you use the data in here? Presumably this will be joined to other data, so how will that join condition be constructed?

Comment: I am making a school time table in which I am storing time.

Comment: You need 6 decimal places of TIMESTAMP precision for a timetable? I'd have thought you could use DATE for that, or TIMESTAMP(0), both of which have times to one-second precision.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but to insert a TIMESTAMP you need to use the SYSTIMESTAMP() function:

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO TIME_PERIOD (START_TIME)
   VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: I want to insert like this to_date('10:00', 'hh:mi')

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a datatype that only stores a time.  You'll need to either store a date, or do something like number of seconds/minutes after midnight.